# Why am i only picking the first cell out of an excel sheet | Python 3

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

The point of the program is to feed a list of urls and get emails from the whois data

```
import whois
import xlrd
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

#excel sheet pull
root = Tk()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("xls files","*.xls"),("all files","*.*")))
workbookName = root.filename
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(workbookName)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

'''
for site in sheet.cell:
    whoisdataset = whois.whois(site)
    for key in whoisdataset:
        if "emails" in key:
            enter code here`if "abuse" not in whoisdataset[key]:
                print (key, whoisdataset[key])
'''

#sheet as matrix
df = pd.read_excel(workbookName)
df.as_matrix()

#Whois email pull
#if you replace "df" with a matrix, it will iterate and work
for website in df:
    whoisdata = whois.whois(website)
    for line in whoisdata:
        if "emails" in line:
            if "abuse" not in whoisdata[line]:
                print (website, ":", line, whoisdata[line])
```

the #excel sheet pull works, and #whois email pull works if i feed it a 1 dimensional matrix, but #sheet as matrix is only giving me the first cell to work with, does anyone know how to make it give me the whole first column as a matrix?

Comment: Please disregard the commented out section

Comment: In general it might be easier to just save the file as a csv and then do pd.read_csv(csv_file_name)

Comment: It would be great if you could add a sample file so others could reproduce.